# How do I change a tooltip font in Google Visualization API GeoChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

It always defaults to Arial. Is there any way to walk generated SVG and change it dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem with the tooltip fonts in IE7/8, the following will set the size and font but numbers / data (not the label) still wants to render serif. Other browsers will pick this up correctly:

```
tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 12 } }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting that.

Answer (score 0):

It is case-sensitive, try 'Verdana' with a capital 'V'.